# With snipMate, how do I add specific snippets for mySpecial.html file only?

Tags: vim, snipmate

In my vim environment, I want to add a few specific snippets that should only be active when I am editing *mySpecial.html* file.

Since this file is an html file I want it to have the html filetype. But on the other hand, if I edit any other html file, I don't want the specific snippets to be active. So, it seems I cannot use the standard filetype mechanism for this.

Is there any solution to my problem?

Answer (score 2):

For the original (Michael Sanders) snipMate, I've defined the following command:

```
:command! -bar -nargs=1 -complete=filetype AddSnippets silent call ExtractSnipsFile(g:snippets_dir . <q-args> . '.snippets', &l:filetype)
```

With that, you can interactively or through an autocmd add the snippets:

```
:autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile mySpecial.html AddSnippets mySpecial
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an interesting feature request.

In the mean time, you can try this simpler variant of Carlo's solution:

1. Put your custom snippets in `~/.vim/snippets/foo.snippets`.
2. Add the following line to your `~/.vimrc`:

   ```
   augroup mySpecialHTML
       autocmd!
       autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile mySpecial.html set filetype=html.foo
   augroup END
   ```

Comment: Ah, there is always something new to learn about vim, I did not know about augroup feature :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define a new filetype just for your *mySpecial.html*

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile mySpcial.html set filetype=myHtml
```

And in that filetype you can reuse the html highlights group, plus your custom snippets.
Does this sound reasonable?

Comment: It sounds reasonable *if* reuse doesn't imply copy/paste.